# MySQL: Copy longtext into a JSON column

Tags: mysql, json

In my `MySQL` database, I have a `longtext` column that stores a JSON object.
I just learned MySQL has a `JSON` datatype that might give me better encoding.

**How can I convert my `longtext` column into a `JSON` column?**

Specifically, I'd like to first create a new column and copy all the data into it as the `JSON` format. Then, once I'm sure it worked properly, I can delete my `longtext` column.

My table is like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
   Id integer primary key,
   Data longtext,
   CreatedDate text,
   ModifiedDate text
)
```

Comment: If you don't want to update the column in place, just use `UPDATE MyTable SET new_column = data` to copy

Comment: But keep in mind your LONGTEXT might be storing a string that is not valid JSON. If you try to copy it into a JSON column, it must be valid. You might have to clean up the content before you can do the UPDATE.